# Cannot create BitmapImage from a chosen photo from phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to implement a Windows Phone 8 App that works with image handling, trying it to port it from a Windows 8 App. But I got stuck quite quickly, at the beginning.

What I want to achieve is to select some pictures from the phone and show them in my app, in a similar way they look in an album. For this, I've tried some MVVM technique, also. But I'm given an error when I'm trying to create a `BitmapImage` from the file `Stream` saying I'm out of range...

Here's my model :

```
public class SelectedPhoto : IDisposable
{
    public Stream Data { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }

    public SelectedPhoto(string name, Stream data)
    {
        Name = name;

        Data = new MemoryStream();
        data.CopyTo(Data);

        Image = new BitmapImage();
        Image.SetSource(Data); //Here's the Argument Exception. 
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Data.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So I'm given the exception quite in the constructor... and I use this in code in a `PhotoChooserTask` like this :

```
private void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        PhotosViewModel.AddPhoto(new SelectedPhoto(e.OriginalFileName, e.ChosenPhoto));
    }
}
```

The Argument Exception says : Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection. But I'm not manipulating the Stream in any way, I just need it as it is to create the BitmapImage from it, as I've looked after some examples.

How can I get the BitmapImage of a selected image file from phone in this case? Or much better, how can I get it directly as a WriteableBitmap? Because later on, I'm planning on doing some pixel manipulation.

Any type of approach is welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your code, call the `Seek` method to go back to the beginning of your stream:

```
public SelectedPhoto(string name, Stream data)
{
    Name = name;

    Data = new MemoryStream();
    data.CopyTo(Data);

    Data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Image = new BitmapImage();
    Image.SetSource(Data); //Here's the Argument Exception. 
}
```

That said, why are you duplicating the stream? You could directly use `data`.

Comment: So the Stream Seek was the problem... Silly me, I removed stream duplicate and it seems to be working fine, now, Thank you!